# Should I change the issuer of a claim in IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

When I receive claims from external systems, (Social medias, other platforms etc), when I fetch the claims, their `Issuer` and `OriginalIssuer` property tend to be named after the platform the user used to authenticate with (oidc).

Do I leave those unchanged, when I import them to my database, or do I change the `Issuer` property's value to "`LOCAL_AUTHORITY`", to signal that my identity provider is actually the one storing them, which were issued originally by X? (`Originalissuer` stays unchanged)

Comment: In what table do you save Issuer and OriginalIssuer claims? AspNetUserClaims?

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin I'm not using ASP.NET Identity. Not a fan of ORM. (Identity Server offers EF/ASP.NET which ends up using EF)